# Move postfix's vmail folder

Tags: email, postfix

I have CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810, Postfix + Dovecot, Apache/2.4.39.
I'm getting low on free space. I have mounted a new disk drive in the meanwhile, so i'm looking for a secure way to move my vmail folder to a new location (not another server) and to accomplish this without any downtime with my emails. 
Is it enough to change in my postfix's main.cf

```
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/vmail
```

to

```
virtual_mailbox_base = /mnt/new_folder
```

and to copy all of the files from `/var/vmail` to a `/mnt/new_folder` location?

Answer (score 0):

If someone was wondering the same:
Stop POSTFIX and DOVECOT services.
In next files, replace lines which contain /var/vmail:

**/etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf**:

```
mail_location = maildir:/var/vmail/%d/%n
```

**/etc/dovecot/dovecot-mysql.conf:**

```
password_query = SELECT username as user, password, concat('/ var /vmail/', maildir) as userdb_home, concat('maildir:/ var /vmail/', maildir) as userdb_mail, 101 as userdb_uid, 12 as userdb_gid FROM mailbox WHERE username = '%u' AND active = '1'
user_query = SELECT concat('/ var /vmail/', maildir) as home, concat('maildir:/ var /vmail/', maildir) as mail, 101 AS uid, 12 AS gid, CONCAT('*:messages=0:bytes=', quota) as quota_rule FROM mailbox WHERE username = '%u' AND active = '1'
```

**/etc/postfix/main.cf**

```
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/vmail
```

to desired destination, for example:

```
/mnt/vmail
```

Start POSTFIX and DOVECOT, and also restart services.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest solution would be to mount the new disk directly at `/var/mail`, for example:

- stop Postfix and Dovecot
- move /var/mail away: `mv /var/mail /var/mail.bak`
- create a new `/var/mail`
- mount the new disk at `/var/mail`
- copy the old data from `/var/mail.bak` to `/var/mail`
- restart Postfix and Dovecot
- remove `/var/mail.bak` once you've verified that everything is ok